# How to find out long running queries in sqlserver 2005?

Tags: performance-monitoring

Is there any command or way to find long running queries in sqlserver 2005? if else please sugesst me

thanks in advance
Koteswar Rao

Answer (score 1):

Try [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using T-SQL [SQL SERVER – 2008 – 2005 – Find Longest Running Query – TSQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/23/sql-server-2008-2005-find-longest-running-query-tsql-part-2/) and here is a way using [SQL Profiler Using Profiler to Identify Poorly Performing Queries](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/performance_audit_part8_p1.aspx).